# Integration using Residue Theorem on Hankel functions

Tags: integration, contour-integration, bessel-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

I am trying to solve below integration. I believe that residue method would be the best approach to solve the integration.

$$S=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{H^{(1)}_{0}(ak)H^{(2)}_{0}(bk)}{k-p}-\frac{H^{(2)}_{0}(ak)H^{(1)}_{0}(bk)}{k+p}dk$$

However, I have some difficulty to find a proper contour for this. Small help is highly appriciated!

Comment: @tired thank you.Ill try

Comment: @tired: a keyhole contour won't work with Bessel functions, as they will diverge along the imaginary axis.

Comment: @ RonGordon I am having the same issue. Specially when dealing with neumann function